# How to fix a locale warning from perl in windows 7

Tags: perl

I have installed `ActivePerl-5.8.9.829-MSWin32-x86-294280` on my windows 7.

Whenever I run any Perl script, I get following error :

```
Perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
Perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LC_ALL = "C",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
Perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I tried setting through environment variable and cmd but it didn't help.

Kindly help because my further installations depends on Perl.

Comment: PS: I have tried many suggestions but nothing helped.

Comment: Can you try Dwimperl and Stawberry perl.?

Comment: I cant. I want specific version for my further installations.

Comment: "I tried setting through environment variable and cmd but it didnt help" What did you do and how did it not work?  Did you set a system variable (lower pane in the wretched Environment Variables dialog)?

Comment: in cmd I did  set LC_ALL=C

Comment: and set LANG=C. In environment variables I added these two variables in user variables.

Comment: Hussain are u saying k I should restore my windows and re instal active perl???

Comment: I would suggest that you need to - you're running a very old version, and ActiveState only support the newest releases.

Answer (score 2):

I solved that warning by:

> Go to control Panel-->Region and Language-->Formats.

In formats tab your Format should be `English(United States)`.

Answer (score 0):

`set LC_ALL=C` should be the right anwser !

Comment: since this is the higher result for this problem even today, for powershell users the command is: `$env:LC_ALL="C"`